# share data between sibling components while both of them use *ngIf

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

So I have a parent component, that hosts 2 sibling components.
something like this

```
<div *ngif="somecode()">
 <sibling1>
 </sibling1>
</div>

<div *ngif="somecode()">
 <sibling1 [dataParams]=sibling1object.somedata>
 </sibling1>
</div>
```

so I get the error that sibling1object.somedata is undefined but when I remove ngIf() from 1st div, the error disappears. 
It doesn't matter if *ngIf resolves to true or false. so i get the error even when sibling1 successfully loads.

Comment: Try `*ngIf` instead of `*ngif`

Answer (score 2):

Use `[hidden]="!somecode()"` instead of `*ngIf="somecode()"`

Answer (score 1):

Please add following code in parent.component.ts

```
 public siblingOneLoaded: boolean = false;
 ngOnDestroy(): void {
        if (sibling1object.somedata) {
            this.siblingOneLoaded = true;
        }
    }
```

Add following code to html file

```
 <div *ngIf="siblingOneLoaded">
        <sibling1 [dataParams]=sibling1object.somedata>
        </sibling1>
    </div>
```